# "de" ou "du" quand un morceau de la phrase est entre tirets

Tags: accord, syntaxe

Je peux fusionner les deux phrases suivantes:

> Il a lu ce livre malgré sa mauvaise réputation.
>
> Il a lu ce livre à cause de sa mauvaise réputation.

en:

> Il a lu ce livre malgré -ou peut-être à cause de- sa mauvaise réputation.

Maintenant je veux faire la même chose mais en remplaçant "sa mauvaise réputation" par "le fait qu'on le lui ait interdit":

> Il a lu ce livre malgré le fait qu'on le lui ait interdit.
>
> Il a lu ce livre à cause du fait qu'on le lui ait interdit.

Que peux donner la phrase fusionnant les deux ? Je vois plusieurs possibilités mais toutes me semblent poser problème:

> Il a lu ce livre malgré -ou peut-être à cause de- le fait qu'on le lui ait interdit.
>
> Il a lu ce livre malgré -ou peut-être à cause du- fait qu'on le lui ait interdit.

Je voudrais éviter de répéter le mot "fait" comme dans:

> Il a lu ce livre malgré le fait -ou peut-être à cause du fait- qu'on le lui ait interdit.

Comment: My tags are not good, but I don't see what could work here.

Answer (score 3):

En conservant *fait*, on peut écrire :

> Il a lu ce livre malgré le – ou peut-être à cause du – fait qu'on le lui ait interdit.

mais la pause entre *du* et *fait* n'est pas très heureuse.

Answer (score 2):

En choisissant d'autres termes, il est possible de garder le sens de la phrase tout en obtenant la forme désirée. Est-ce que ceci vous conviendrait ?

> Il a lu ce livre bien que - ou peut-être parce que - cela lui a été interdit.

Answer (score 2):

Une variante avec "de par":

> Il a lu ce livre malgré -ou peut-être de par- le fait qu'on le lui ait interdit.